# JSON Schema with ipv4/ipv6/hostname format as keys

Tags: json, jsonschema

If I have a JSON document like:

```json
{
  "142.250.193.14": {},
  "2404:6800:4002:819::200e": {},
  "google.com": {},
}
```

i.e.,  it has ipv4/ipv6 addresses and hostnames as keys and the values are irrelevant to the question. How can I define a JSON schema that uses the built-in formats to check for these, I tried using patternProperties but a regex for all of these is quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `propertyNames` keyword, which lets you use a schema to define the structure of the property name, when it's more complicated than a pattern would allow for.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names

```json
{
  "propertyNames": {
    "anyOf": [
      { "format": "ipv4" },
      { "format": "ipv6" },
      { "format": "hostname" }
    ]
  }
}
```

You need to make sure that your evaluator is validating formats, as that's specified to be disabled by default.

Answer (score -1):

Don't have a full answer for you, but there are a bunch of IPV6 regex examples that come close, like [this one from regexr](https://regexr.com/3bu43).   Those could be a starting point for the JSON.